# Item overlay when scroll up

Tags: android, android-gridview

I've developed an android app, and in one screen there is a gridview with two items by row.

Each item is compounded by an image with a text below.

When the layout is loaded, it shows the elems on the right way, but when I scroll up the get the first ones, there is an overlay of the items that have a multiline text.

[image: Layout when the scrren is loaded]

[image: Layout when the user scroll up]

This is the code of the elems:

**Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/atlas_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:dividerHeight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Item**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/atlas_item_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/atlas_item_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:fontFamily="casual"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The code for adding items to the `GridView` is:

```
final GridView gridView = findViewById(R.id.atlas_list);
AtlasItemAdapter adapter = new AtlasItemAdapter(activity, atlasItems);
gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

where `AtlasItemAdapter` is a custom class extending `ArrayAdapter<AtlasItem>`, overriding the `getView` method.

You can check the app in the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sergiobra.geograpp) to reproduce the behaviour.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you show how you add the items in the GridLayout? I'd suggest you use a RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager as the layout manager

Comment: @LucaNicoletti added

Comment: @LucaNicoletti using a RecycleView with the GridLayoutManager wotks like a charm. And with better performance. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :) EDIT with your solution, or if you want I can post an asnwer

Comment: @LucaNicoletti please, provide you the answer, you give me the clue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not pretty sure why this happens, but what I'd do is: use a RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager as the LayoutManeger.

Here are the files:

`layout.xml`:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/atlasList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

`Activity.java`:

```
RecyclerView myRecycler = findViewById(R.id.atlasList);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 2);
myRecycler.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(atlasList);
myRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
```

`Adapter.java`:

```
class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Viewholder> {
    private List<Atlas> list;
    public MyAdapter(List<Atlas> atlasList) { this.list = atlasList; }

    // needed methods of RecyclerView.Adapter class
}
```